# GetWebTemplates: Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: 2010, web-template

I've created an generic http handler (ashx) that creates sites based on a particular custom web template I have created. However I'm getting a strange error when I execute the `GetWebTemplates` method.

Basically it throws an formatexception with the message

> "Input string was not in a correct format"

Any ideas? My code:

```
  using (SPSite thisSite = new SPSite(web.Site.ID))
            {
                SPWebTemplateCollection templates = thisSite.GetWebTemplates(1033);
                SPWebTemplate siteTemplate = null;

                foreach (SPWebTemplate template in templates)
                {
                    if (template.Title.Equals(title))
                    {
                        siteTemplate = template;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                return siteTemplate;           
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

This indeed is strange. I have tested your code in my development environment and it runs with no errors. Could perhaps your site collection be damaged somehow? I would try creating a fresh site collection (heck, maybe even a fresh web application...) just to check. If it runs OK against the new SPSite, you'll need to figure out what's wrong with the current one.

Comment: So, have you figured out what the problem was?